# When writing chaincode on Fabric, am I limited to the functions defined by the chaincode stub?

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode

For instance, when I start a js project with the VScode Hyperledger plugin, I get a smart contract like this:

```
onst { Contract } = require('fabric-contract-api');

class MyAssetContract extends Contract {

    //****I added stuff */
    async nameSomething(ctx, myAssetId, nameToGive){
        const buffer = await ctx.stub.getState(myAssetId);
        if (!exists) {
            throw new Error(`The my asset ${myAssetId} does not exist`);
        }
        //NAME SOMETHING HERE?
    }

    async myAssetExists(ctx, myAssetId) {
        const buffer = await ctx.stub.getState(myAssetId);
        return (!!buffer && buffer.length > 0);
    }

    async createMyAsset(ctx, myAssetId, value) {
        const exists = await this.myAssetExists(ctx, myAssetId);
        if (exists) {
            throw new Error(`The my asset ${myAssetId} already exists`);
        }
        const asset = { value };
        const buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(asset));
        await ctx.stub.putState(myAssetId, buffer);
    }

    async readMyAsset(ctx, myAssetId) {
        const exists = await this.myAssetExists(ctx, myAssetId);
        if (!exists) {
            throw new Error(`The my asset ${myAssetId} does not exist`);
        }
        const buffer = await ctx.stub.getState(myAssetId);
        const asset = JSON.parse(buffer.toString());
        return asset;
    }

    async updateMyAsset(ctx, myAssetId, newValue) {
        const exists = await this.myAssetExists(ctx, myAssetId);
        if (!exists) {
            throw new Error(`The my asset ${myAssetId} does not exist`);
        }
        const asset = { value: newValue };
        const buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(asset));
        await ctx.stub.putState(myAssetId, buffer);
    }

    async deleteMyAsset(ctx, myAssetId) {
        const exists = await this.myAssetExists(ctx, myAssetId);
        if (!exists) {
            throw new Error(`The my asset ${myAssetId} does not exist`);
        }
        await ctx.stub.deleteState(myAssetId);
    }

}

module.exports = MyAssetContract;
```

As you can see, I tried to add my own function by naming something. I'm coming from Ethereum so I'm used to defining variables and naming them like a conventional program. However, I feel as though I need to adhere to what is defined by the stub. Is that the case? If that is the case, is the ledger updated by Fabric's API or can I explicitly write permission in the contract?

Answer (score 1):

The stub APIs provide a few things:

- access to ledger state via put/get operations
- convenience functions for accessing transaction context

You are free to implement any logic you want in your smart contract, but if you want to read and/or write data from/to the ledger, you need to use the stub APIs.

A typical function will read some state from the ledger (usually based on an input to the function), run some logic (change the value, check a value) and then write new and/or updated state to the ledger.